# GStreamer RTSP-Server transfering custom GstMeta data to the client

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp, gstreamer-1.0

I need to share a custom Timestamp for each frame to the client. My idea was to add into the GstMeta a custom MetaData-Structure that shares the Timestamp to the client.

For sharing the video we are using the rtsp-server for GStreamer. Does anybody know if it is possible to transfer any kind of GstMeta data with that server?

Comment: Afaik RTP does not offer any means to transmit per frame metadata in its protocol..

Comment: @FlorianZwoch do you know any mechanismn to calculate the latency between video source and rendering time on a client? (Latency is forced to be zero)